# Windows 10 gray screen after login

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, display

My Windows 10 desktop has begun displaying a completely gray screen immediately after login. I recently installed new graphics drivers for Ubuntu and I suspect that my graphics drivers for Windows 10 were deleted during this process. Is there any way for me to reinstall graphics drivers when I cannot see the screen, or possibly install into the Windows partition through Ubuntu? Graphics card is an RTX 2080. I have tried booting into Safe Mode, but the result is the same, with the addition of a non-functional flashing taskbar.

Comment: "I suspect that my graphics drivers for Windows 10 were deleted during this process" I don't see how this is possible with 2 different Operating systems on different partitions.

Comment: @Moab It doesn’t make sense but I’ve made no other recent changes and I don’t know what else could’ve caused it

Comment: Your theory is flawed and is not possible (even if it was removed it wouldn’t cause your issue).  It is not possible to install Windows drivers from within Linux

Comment: @Ramhound What do you think might’ve caused it?

Comment: Maybe a driver update installed by Windows update silently. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power down the PC, start the PC, before you get to the login screen when Windows is booting press and hold the Power Button until the PC shuts off.

Do this three times or until you get the Automatic Repair screen, let repair load and run its Diagnosis, when that is done click the Advanced Options button when it appears, then Troubleshoot button, then Advanced Options, then System Restore button.

When restore loads hit Next button, now you will see your restore points, highlight either the first one or second it the date is not over 10 days old (make note of the name and date of the restore point), once selected hit next. This process takes a long while depending on the speed of your hard drive, be patient and Do Not interrupt the process.

If it does not solve it start over and pick an older restore point that is next in line.

Hopefully this will solve the grey screen issue.

Comment: Thanks! This seems like a good general solution I can use in future. Hopefully whatever caused it doesn’t happen again